# Is it safe to save LinkedIn SecretKey in of my code?

Tags: ios, swift, linkedin-api, oauth-2.0

I want to ask you, is it safe to save LinkedIn ConsumerKey and ConsumerSecret inside of my code, like constants?

If it's not safe, what is the right way of authentication with LinkedIn?

Comment: Never put a private key inside code that is released... it essentially becomes public if you do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even compiled code, it would still be possible to get the key out if someone was determined.

Generally, the user would pass credentials to your server and on your server side you would store the private key, and pass an expiring token back to the user so they can access the service.  It looks like LinkedIn can handle the server-side for you, so you can do minimal processing on your server-side.

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2